# Install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 8

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, uefi, windows-8

I have windows 8.1 installed on my PC which uses UEFI boot. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04
So I have create bootable USB with Ubuntu 16.04 and installed it successfully. and grub bootloader now is working and i can login and logout to Ubuntu.
The problem is when i try to open Windows 8 i got the following error

```
Your PC needs to be repaired.
The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
File:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD Error code: 0xc000000f.

You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media
```

I followed the instructions described [Microsoft question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/the-boot-configuration-data-for-your-pc-is-missing/7078bdf8-4396-46f1-97a6-7b7f4aaedab8?auth=1) and using windows installation media i opened command prompt and write this:

```
> BOOTREC/FIXMBR
> BOOTREC/FIXBOOT
> BOOTREC/REBUILDBCD
```

I have restored windows 8.1 and UEFI bootloader. It login automatically to windows. and Ubuntu is also installed but cannot find a way to select it

**Is there a way to make UEFI let me choose between Windows and Ubuntu? Or could i return to grub without making errors on Windows? I need a solution to use Ubuntu with Windows**

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? UEFI and BIOS boot are not compatible. But even if not same boot mode, you should be able to select Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu.  Also have you turned off fast start up in Windows?  Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Grub should be able to do this, but you didn't tell it to look for your Windows installation before rebooting.  Fixing your MBR caused it to forget your Ubuntu, so in some sense you're starting over from the beginning.

I recently did an alongside install with Windows 7 and got it working, but I don't have UEFI.  Did you do grub-install and grub-update before rebooting out of your Ubuntu install?  If you boot from your Ubuntu USB again you may be able to run those commands against your installed partition.  Otherwise, perhaps just reinstall Ubuntu and then run those commands before rebooting?

I was able to fix some of my errors using boot-repair.  It can remove grub and reinstall it.  I was booted into the instance I was repairing, I'm not sure whether it can do it for one that's not booted.

I don't know enough to give more specific advice, but hopefully these ideas give you some possible ways forward.